# Datamaps - Loading different country maps along with world map

Tags: javascript, datamaps

I am trying to project different maps based on the functionality. Initially, I am loading world map. If the user clicks "usa" I want to navigate to a different page and show "USA" map. If the user clicks "RUS", I want to showcase "RUS" map.

The problem I am facing is when I include "datamaps.world.js" and "datamaps.usa.js", i get an erro saying,

```
datamaps-all.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'world' of undefined
```

This is caused because I am trying to load both datamaps.world and datamps.usa. or any other country for that matter.

Is there a workaround for this ?

I am using Jade for templating system,

```
script(src="/javascripts/d3.v3.min.js")
script(src="/javascripts/topojson.v1.min.js")
script(src="/javascripts/d3-queue.v3.min.js")
script(src="/javascripts/datamaps-usa.js")
script(src="/javascripts/datamaps.world.mod.js")
script(src="/javascripts/datamaps-all.js")
```

I tried the below script to dynamically load different Javascript on every page loads, but it is not working.

```
script.
    if ((window.location.href).indexOf("country=USA") <= -1) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "/javascript/datamaps-usa.js";
    } else {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "/javascript/datamaps-world.js";
    }
```

Datamaps declaration:

```
var map = new Datamap({
    scope: 'world',
    element: document.getElementById('canvas'),
    projection: 'mercator',
    height:900,
    width:null,
    responsive: true,
    geographyConfig: {
        hideAntarctica: true,
        hideHawaiiAndAlaska : false,
        borderWidth: 1.5,
        borderOpacity: 0,
        borderColor: '#ffffff'
    }, .... [truncated]
```

I plan to project all countries. I do want to know how to achieve this ? Requesting community help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, i found a solution to this problem. It's just keeping the 2 files separately and loading it whenever needed.

Written a detailed explanation here. https://sketchingjournal.blogspot.com/2016/09/datamaps-dynamically-loading-map-based.html

Comment: the given link is inactive, please post a valid url or solution